# How to duplicate field value during migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I had a model that only stored a single value:

```
 class Number(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
```

Now I want to change the behavior so the number I need is not unique anymore.

```
class Number(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

How to tell the migration to use the ID field as the "one-off value"?

Comment: It when you try makemigrations and ask u what do with already exist records?

Comment: yes. how to tell it to take the value from the other field?

Comment: Are you wanting to transport was is currently in the `id` field to the `number` field?

Comment: yes, i want to copy it there! not rename the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this sort of thing is to add the field like you've already done and run that migration

```
python manage.py schemamigration your_app --auto
python manage.py migrate your_app
```

Then you can create a datamigration like so

```
python manage.py datamigration your_app copy_id_to_number
```

Then open the migration file that was just created with the above command and change `def forward(self, orm)` like so

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    for num in orm.Number.objects.all():
        if num.id:
            num.number = num.id
```

Then you will want to run this migration

```
python manage.py migrate your_app
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in two migrations. The first one would add the field, with a one-off default of 0. The second one would copy over the values: this could be done with a RunPython function that does something like this:

```
from django.db.models import F
Number.objects.update(number=F('id'))
```